# Пересекающиеся транзакции на запись sqlite cordova, непонятная ошибка

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-sqlite

В приложении cordova на андроид непонятная ошибка. Есть две таблицы - аа и бб. И две транзакции, одна пишет в аа, вторая в аа и бб. Первая в фоне на таймере, вторая интерфейсная.

Если вторая транзакция начинается во время работы первой, то по результате запись в бб есть, а в аа записи только от первой транзакции, а от второй нет. Как так может быть? При том, что insert во второй транзакции возвращает id записи в аа и в ошибку не попадает.

upd.
Все таки нашелся делит. Ситуация немного другая. В первой транзакции чтение таблицы на предмет разрешения делита. И удаление записей. Между этими двумя операциями транзакция два успевает добавить запись. В итоге она удаляется. Как этого избежать,
может есть какие ручные блокировки для изменений? Пока вижу вариант формировать список записей для удаления, а не по фильтру удалять

Comment: `Id` присутствует по итогу в таблице `aa`? Обе транзакции делают только `insert`?

Comment: Все таки нашелся делит. Ситуация немного другая. В первой транзакции чтение таблицы на предмет разрешения делита. И удаление записей. Между этими двумя операциями транзакция два успевает добавить запись. В итоге она удялется. Как этого избежать?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю новая запись не должна иметь разрешение на delete, но возможно я что-то упустил из вашего объяснения. Было бы хорошо если бы вы актуализировали свой вопрос путем правки и добавили некоторый пример того что происходит и какая структура таблиц

Comment: она добавляется между запросом на разрешение и удалением. rs =select ... where isExpired = 0. If rs.length = 0 {delete все строки}. Между этими двумя операциями происходит запись с isExpired =0.

Comment: Делайте через запрос удаления строк где указывайте условие в самом запросе, или приведите свой sql ( но в вопросе с форматированием, не в комментарии) Вам точно не нужно удалять все строки, и у меня есть подозрение что Вы удаление делаете часто, что может быть не оптимальный вариант ( но это только догадки )

Comment: А есть какая то возможность установки блокировки на изменение? Там куча вспомогательных таблиц, в которых флага уже нет.

Comment: Насколько я знаю нет, это все таки лайт

Comment: Спасибо за участие.